# How to compute K and n? [Item-based Collaborative Filtering]

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, recommender-system

I'm currently studying an item-based collaborative filtering algorithm described in [Ul Haq, Raza - Hybrid Recommender System Towards User Satisfaction](http://www.ruor.uottawa.ca/en/handle/10393/24218). I've formulated the algorithm below based on it. I have no problem on steps 1 to 3 but ...

- in step 4 it says there: **Set the threshold value n.**   How can I determine the value of n? Is there a formula for getting the value of it? I already checked it out but there's nothing there.
- in Step 5: **Select the K most similar products in M**. The same question, how can I compute the value of K?

> 1. Retrieve all the item rated by an active user and put it to Q.
> 2. Isolate the users who have rated both the target item (i) and the items rated by the active user in Q, get the item and put it in R.
>      (co-rated items)
> 3. Calculate the item similarities using the Pearson Correlation Coefficient with all the  items (j) in R.
> 4. Set the threshold value n, If the similarity of i and j is greater or equal to n, (sim(i,j) >= n),  Then include it in M.
> 5. Select the K most similar products in M.
> 6. Take the weighted average of the users rating on these similar items K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K and n are so called hyperparameters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization). Although sometimes there is a rule of a thumb, an exhaustive rule would require to take all aspects of the data in the account, so in general one is better off to carefully optimize them via inner (cross-)validation.

cbeleites has described how to do so in [an excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/65156/264) to this question: [Nested cross validation for model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection)