# Backward stepwise regression with cross validation in R

Tags: r, cross-validation, model-selection, caret, stepwise-regression

I would like to do model selection using backward stepwise procedure and cross validation. 
https://www.otexts.org/fpp/5/3

I have used `stepAIC` in `MASS` package  for predictors selection and I would like to see whether cross validation is a better criteria. In other words, I am trying to use cross-validation as a criterion in backward selection procedure *instead* of AIC.

The procedure should start with a full model, drop one predictor at a time, keep the variable if it improves CV and continue until no improvements can be made.

I think that the `rfe` function in the `caret` package may be able to do the job. I would also like to do bootstrapping if possible. If so, how should I specify it? Or are there any functions that can do that?  I have tried writing my own function, but it seems to be beyond my ability. Many thanks.

Comment: `validate` in the `rms` package has the option of allowing backwards selection based on AIC. Do read some of the many posts here on why stepwise methods aren't so good & consider whether (a) you need to do post-hoc model selection, & (b) you ought to apply shrinkage e.g. lasso.

Comment: As @Scortchi alluded, the method you proposed is not based on any good statistical principles. If you really need to do model selection (which is not obvious why this is helpful; weak variables don't hurt models), then you should combine model selection with shrinkage using a method such as elastic net.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question (despite its being pretty clear) - you want to use a performance measure calibrated by cross-validation as a criterion in the backward selection procedure *instead* of AIC. Note that you'll still want to validate this procedure: see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128/nested-cross-validation-for-model-selection). And that it's still stepwise, with all its faults.

Comment: In addition to what Frank Harrell and Scortchi say, you should definitively read Dikran Marsupial's paper about overfitting during such massive model comparison situations: Cawley, G. C. & Talbot, N. L. C.: On Over-fitting in Model Selection and Subsequent Selection Bias in Performance Evaluation, Journal of Machine Learning Research, 11, 2079-2107 (2010).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. As @Scortch clarified, I am trying to use cross-validation as a criterion in backward selection procedure instead of AIC. I have used backwards selection based on AIC and I would to see whether cross-validation is a better criteria.

Comment: See [this page](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/Feature_Selection_Wrapper.html) for details on feature selection wrappers used by `caret` via `train`. Using `method = 'lmStepAIC'` or `method = 'glmStepAIC'` will resample that entire process (if you are interested in that sort of thing)