# What do I make of all classification scores being equal to 1?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, boosting, overfitting

I've built an XGBoost classifier with following code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)  

xgbc = XGBClassifier()  
xgbc.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = xgbc.predict(X_test)  

rep = metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)  
print(rep)
```

And I get the scores as follows.
[image]

Then I performed 5 fold cross-validation:

```
cross_val_score(xgbc, X, y, cv=5)
```

And got the following cv scores.

- 1.0
- 1.0
- 0.99497487
- 0.98994975
- 0.98492462

I'm fairly new to machine learning, and I can't figure out if my  model is pefroming excellently or if it has overfit.

Comment: 0. Welcome to CV.SE. 1. I think you slightly misinterpret what `cross_val_score` returns, these 5 numbers are the performance of the same model on different slices of the data. Please see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a case of the learner (XGBoost here) not giving results summing up to one. What is returned by [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) are the scores from our learner (`xgbc` here) for each run of the cross-validation.
In general, the performance attained in your test set is exceptionally high, note thought that if we use a dataset for model selection, we want another independent (or at least hold-out) dataset for evaluation. Here as we are using `X` in its entirety in `cross_val_score` we do get a somewhat optimistic view of `xgbc`'s performance as at least part of the `X` has been used to train the model as well as report is performance, at first instance, I would suggest using `X_test`/`y_test`.
(Comparing different learners as a whole needs to be done via nested CV - see the CV.SE thread on: *[Nested cross validation for model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65128)* as a starting point).